# How to run bash commands from array?

Tags: shell

I have three commands I running in shell file (app.sh):

```
docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.my-app1.yml push my-app1
docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.my-app2.yml push my-app2
docker-compose -f .docker/docker-compose.my-app3.yml push my-app3
```

how to create array and pass the values to command with foreach?

say if it's was nodejs I'll do:

```
['my-app1', 'my-app2', 'my-app3'].forEach(i => {

  … `-f .docker/docker-compose.${i}.yml push ${i}` ...;
})
```

Comment: If it's Linux then something like this in script. for n in $(cat lists.txt )
do
    echo "Working on $n file name now"
    # do something on $n below, say count line numbers
    # wc -l "$n"
done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH you can have arrays and for loops as follows

```
arr=( 'my-app1' 'my-app2' 'my-app3' )

for i in "${arr[@]}" ; do
   docker-compose -f ".docker/docker-compose.${i}.yml" push "${i}"
done
```

Note, that you do not need to use commas to separate array elements as whitespace is a token separator in BASH.